# Post content and reply comment using react

Tags: reactjs, state

I am new in react and for educational purposes, I am trying to make social media app that contains a discussion section. I made a recursive textbox for that. Now, I need a line number for new content as well as for the replied comment. Here submit button is used to post new content and the reply button is used to comment on existing content. How can I do this?
[image: Here is UI screenshot]

Here is my code

````
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import ContentBoxWithVotes from "./content_box_with_votes";
    import styled from "@emotion/styled";
    
    // creating a bundler component
    const Bundle = styled.div`
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    `;
    
    const ContentBoxRepeatWtihVotesFunctional = () => {
      const [buttonName, setButtonName] = useState("stop");
      const [isExit, setIsExit] = useState(false);
      const [count, setCount] = useState([1]);
      const [lineNumber, setLineNumber] = useState(1);
    
     
    
    const toogelButton = (text) => {
      if (buttonName === "stop") {
          setButtonName("Restart");
          setIsExit(true);
        } else {
          setButtonName("stop");
          setIsExit(false);
        }
      };
    
    function handleReply(lineNumber){
      
        setLineNumber(lineNumber+1);
    
      };
    
      const handleChange = (index, value) => {
        // setValue({
        //   values:{
        //     ...values,
        //         [index]: value
        //     }}
        // );
      };
    
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
    
        if (!isExit) {
          const lastCount = count[count.length - 1] + 1;
          setCount([...count, lastCount]);
         
        }
      };
     
    
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {count.map((key) => (
              <Bundle>
                <label>{lineNumber[key] } </label>
                <ContentBox
                  value={key}
                  onChange={(event) => handleChange(event.target.value)}
                />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="button" value="Reply"  onClick= {handleReply}/>
              </Bundle>
            ))}
       
    
    
          </form>
         
          <button onClick={toogelButton}>{buttonName}</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default ContentBoxRepeatWtihVotesFunctional;
    ```
    
    **code inside ContentBox is**
    
    
    ```
    import React from 'react';
    
    const ContentBox = () => {
      return(
          <input type="text" placeholder='Add your content line here ... '/>
       
      );
    };
    
    export default ContentBox;
````